# Dropping locked tables from Mysql

Tags: mysql

I set up a table from Mysql locked when created, and I thought I deleted using the drop command. But when I try to start all over again with creating a table by the same name, I get an error saying Table '`tname`' already exists even with the drop if exists command.

To further illustrate my point ... here is the table I created at the beginning

```
       DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `one`;
       /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
       /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
       CREATE TABLE `one` (
       //
       ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
       /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

       --
       -- Dumping data for table `one`
       --

       LOCK TABLES `one` WRITE;
       /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `one` DISABLE KEYS */;
       /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `one` ENABLE KEYS */;
       UNLOCK TABLES;

       -----
```

Then **drop table one;** ... Its not there anymore when I issued **show tables** in the database, but when I try to create a table named one, it says **Table '`one`' already exist**

```
       DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `one`;
       /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
       /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
       CREATE TABLE `one` (
       //
       ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
      /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

      ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table '`dbname`.`one`' already exists
```

Comment: refer this: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70171

Comment: @jmail: "refer _to_ this", and I'm not sure that the bug is relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your data directory and check if one.ibd or one.frm file exists there. If exists then delete that file and check again.

If after deleting still getting problem them create same table in another db and move one.ibd and one.frm files from that db to this db and then drop this table.

Hope your problem will be solved by this.

Comment: Thanks. I did delete the file from the directory (which is by default /var/lib/mysql, right?) initially. But no changes. My intention in deleting the table is it holds a huge dataset (GBs) and even though I deleted the records and all, still no change in my harddisk. I am running a little short of the memory here.

Comment: If you've deleted a large file and your HD space has not changed, try emptying your trash.

Comment: deletion does not free space, to get space you have to do either optimize table, or backup and then restore the table or alter the table (just change engine same as was earlier) these are the ways to get space after bulk deletion.

Comment: It's also empty. I think I have done something wrong somewhere. That should be it. I am trying to duplicate the database now.

Comment: Some time server does not free space even after deleting some heavy files, for this you need to restart mysql to get space. Please try this.

Comment: I restart mysql. But the space is not changed, so does the table. Its confusing since it says "Unknown table 'tname'" when I issued drop table command. But when I try to create one with same name, it goes like ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table '`DBName`.`TName`' already exists

Comment: Now there is 2 issues first you were not able to create a table named one, have you resolved it. Second is space issue on server, its reason can be that innodb_file_per_table is off in your system, if it will be off then data will be stored in single file and to make space you need to backup of full db and then restored the db. So check it and share details.

Comment: How can I activate the innodb_file_per_table?

Comment: Step1: First take your all db's backup,  step2: put innodb_filer_per_table in your my.cnf file (my.ini if windows),  step3: restart mysql ,   step4: restore now all dbs backup. Now earch table data will be stored in their own ibd file means each table should have 2 files .frm and .ibd

Comment: Thanks very much. My DB is bulky, so I am gonna set up that later. Where should I put innodb_filer_per_table in the my.cnf? Under some parameter value or something? Sorry for successive questions. newbie here.

Comment: simply update this line "innodb_file_per_table" under [mysqld] section at any place like just after data dir or any where else.

Comment: Thanks. I updated that to a value of 1. I am just wondering, how could one's memory will be freed after dropping a gigantic database from Mysql? It stays like forever once recorded, and will the database name not be used to create another one EVEN AFTER DELETING THE WHOLE DATABASE??? Thanks for your big help.

Comment: What if I reinstall Mysql after manually deleting the humongous (around 40 GB now) /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 file? Can I do that with no system crush or anything? Hope I can.

Comment: You can go as per following steps: 1. take backup of your mysql directory /var/lib/mysql. 2. Take backup of your all dbs with mysql db (rights) by mysqldump 3. delete all files from your mysql directory 4.un-install and again install mysql with innodb_file_per_table  5. Now new mysql files will be created 6. Now restored your data, now your data will be stored in seperate .ibd files and ibdata1 files size will be nominal.

Comment: Thanks. I get my space back, but when I tried mysql to install again, it failed. start: Job failed to start and the status shown "mysql stop/waiting" ... I tried it with sudo,but no changes. Any clue?

Comment: It's found in /var/log/mysql folder, right? Too long to copy-paste here. Where should I attach that file to you? Thanks for the help again. I created a new thread here ... but its marked as duplicate and off-topic ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830739/mysql-5-5-failed-to-start-error

Comment: The Error part in the log file is this ... 140403 10:18:01 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'innodb_filer_per_table=1'
140403 10:18:01 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: just update innodb_file_per_table instead of =1, if you are passing it from out side then you need to mention =1 but in my.cnf just need to update it without value 1.

Comment: Okay, but no changes. And how can I change the content of /usr/sbin/mysqld file ... it says unknown variable 'innodb_filer_per_table=1' in my log file. Its innodb_file_per_table in my.cnf, so I have no idea where did that comes from in /usr/sbin/mysql.

Comment: After change did you restart mysql, also share your mysql version...also errors in your other thread is showing that mysql did not install properly...

Comment: Mysql version is 5.5. It can't restart ... when I issue "$ sudo service mysql restart" it returns
stop: Unknown instance: 
start: Job failed to start

Comment: problem seems in mysql installation, first un-install mysql then install mysql then start mysql (no need to put innodb_file_per_table as mysql 5.5 have this feature by default), if mysql is started successfully then restore your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to purge sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common to completely remove mysql. Now it works. On down side, it also delete ROS packages while I use purge, which I don't get what's the connection with mysql. Anyways, for the time being, my problem is solved, thanks in major part to you.